# How to get the path of a youtube_dl download?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get the path of a youtube-dl download. My current attempt is to reconstruct the path of the `outtmpl` setting:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    yinfo = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
filename = f"{yinfo['title']}.{yinfo['ext']}"
print(filename)
```

This feels like a bit of a hack (breaking if `outtmpl` changes, for instance). It's also giving me incorrect results. The saved file is `Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mkv`, but the printed filename is `Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp4` (different extension).

What is the simplest way to get the name of the downloaded file? (I realize I can specify the file extension, but I would like to keep the behavior of youtube-dl choosing the best format for the video.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to specify which format `youtube-dl` must download. If not, the library reassembles in another container audio + video, changing file extension in order to get best results. If you ask explicitly `mp4` format in options, the printed filename will be `Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp4`, as well as saved file. Asking `webm` format will give you `Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).webm`, and so on

Comment: Thanks! However, I want to keep the behavior of using the best format for the video. (I've updated the question accordingly.)

Comment: @dug "best" format isn't ready to download on YouTube. Higher video bitrates are always without any audio, and you must download the two separate streams for merging in a second stage with `ffmpeg`(that's another story!). So, there are many video formats for every url, but audio stops nearly at 160Kbit, not proportionally "growing" with high video bitrates

Comment: So, `youtube-dl` picks the "best" option with audio + video :-)